# Why using checkout and reset naming for the file-level operations in git?

Tags: git

After reading [this](https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/resetting-checking-out-and-reverting/summary) nice article on git Reset, Checkout, and Revert I still don't quite understand the connection between some commands naming and their behaviour. Let's take a look at the table below:

[image]

On the commit-level the naming-behaviour correspondences seem fine to me, but on the file-level instead of typing `git checkout <some_file>` I would rather go with `git reset <some_file>` because what we are essentially doing here is resetting.

And in for the unstaging procedure I would expect to have something like `git unstage <some_file>`. Much more understandable and nice.

So, is this weird naming for the file-level `checkout` and `unstage` is just a historical legacy or there is some logical reasons behind it?

Comment: Use Git or shell aliases to create custom name names if you want command names like "unstage."

Comment: Well, that's Git for you. As for `git unstage`, you can define an alias for that: `git config --global alias.unstage "reset HEAD --"`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a combination of historical and Git's general propensity to make one command do five logically-unrelated things as long as all five of those things use similar source-code level operations.

Since `git reset` works on the index in the commit -> index direction, and "unstage" is an index operation consisting of copying from commit to index, it's jammed into the reset command.

Since `git checkout` does commit -> index -> work-tree operations, and reverting a file to a committed version requires a commit -> work-tree copy, it's jammed into checkout.

(Just to be especially confusing, Mercurial has a `revert` operation that affect only files, while Git's `git revert` makes a new commit that backs out a previous commit, which Mercurial calls `hg backout`.  As two commenters noted, you can set up aliases, although I find this lends itself to the old saying about how standards are so great: "there are so many to choose from, and if you don't like any of them, you can just make up your own!")